# Creating an OS X .pkg from a Windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, continuous-integration, package

We use GitLab CI with GitLab runners to build our software from C# source code. At the end of the CI pipeline we generate .msi files. We also want to generate .pkg files for OS X, but how can we do that on the same machine?

Another option was to simply have a Mac for CI as well, but that would require us to build the source twice which would be redundant.